# Задать направление сортировки (ASC/DESC) методу репозитория в аннотации @Query, используя значение параметра метода

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Пишу метод репозитория, хочу реализовать его при помощи аннотации `@Query`. Запрос должен доставать список всех пользователей, отсортированный по количеству оставленных пользователем сообщений.

Такой метод может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@Query(value = """
            SELECT u FROM User u
            INNER JOIN u.postedMessages
            GROUP BY u.id
            ORDER BY COUNT(*)
            """)
List<User> findAllByOrderByMessagesCount();
```

Однако я хочу, чтобы в метод можно было в качестве параметра передавать направление сортировки. Например, просто строкой, принимающей значения `ASC`/`DESC`. Я представляю себе что-то наподобие такого:

```
@Query(value = """
            SELECT u FROM User u
            INNER JOIN u.postedMessages
            GROUP BY u.id
            ORDER BY COUNT(*)
            :direction
            """)
List<User> findAllByOrderByMessagesCount(@Param("direction") String direction);
```

Однако это не работает, так как, насколько я понял, подобная подстановка возможна только в рамках каких-то выражений, по типу сравнения в `WHERE` и так далее.

Я придумал вариант с использованием параметра в виде объекта от класса `Sort`. Передавать его можно так:

```
JpaSort.unsafe(direction, "COUNT(*)")
```

Это будет осуществлять то, что я хочу, и здесь уже, как видно, проблем с заданием направления нет.

Но мне не нравится то, что ведь сортировка - это, по сути, основная задача метода репозитория, который я реализую. А если `COUNT(*)` перенести куда-то в вызов метода из внешнего мира, то, кажется, это будет как-то некрасиво: отделяем от метода половину его логики, и сам метод получается каким-то бестолковым.

В итоге, **вопрос**: каким образом можно подставить подстроку, определяющую направление сортировки, в аннотацию `@Query` из параметра метода?

Конечно, вполне возможно, что я пытаюсь сделать нечто в целом страшное, поэтому если будут более хорошие идеи насчёт того, как реализовать метод, возвращающий сортированный список и зависящий от направления сортировки, то пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось реализовать то, что я хотел. Не средствами Spring Data JPA, как я предполагал изначально, но зато синтаксисом обычного SQL:

```
@Query(value = """
        SELECT u FROM User u
        LEFT JOIN u.postedMessages pm
        GROUP BY u.id
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN :direction = 'ASC' THEN COUNT(pm.id) END ASC,
            CASE WHEN :direction = 'DESC' THEN COUNT(pm.id) END DESC
        """)
List<User> findAllByOrderByMessagesCountWithDirection(@Param("direction") String direction);
```

Выглядит относительно громоздко, но делает то, что я и задумывал.

Теперь мы легко можем вызывать этот метод из сервисов, передавая в него лишь направление сортировки. А сам метод при этом выполняет всю свою логику: и джойнит таблицы, и группирует, и сразу же неотрывно от этой логики сортирует.